# Is there a way to ask for an email address before you download a file?

Tags: plugins, emails, plugin-digitaldownload

For Wordpress there's a plugin called Email before download (https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-before-download/).
I'd like to ask the user's email address before they are able to download a pdf file.
Is there a plugin that can do this in Craft?
Anyone wants to share their experience for best practices?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple form and if the user submits he gets redirect to the thank you page with the download link. 
Another option is, to send the user the download link via the entered mail. I think that will save you more from trash mails.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The thank you page is indeed a good and more simple option.